# Solving set of differential equations in Maple with boundary conditions

Tags: maple, differential-equations

I am trying to solve a set of coupled differential equations, and I want to check some of my derivations with **Maple**. However, I am not getting the synthax right.

I tried to reproduce my problem in a simple case, which looks as follows:

```
restart;
e1:=diff(P(y),y,y,y,y)=0;
e2:=diff(Q(x,y),y,y)=0;
dsolve([e1,e2]);
cond:=P(0)=0;
dsolve({e1,cond});
dsolve({e1,e2,cond});
dsolve({e1,e2,cond},[P,Q]);
```

So these are uncoupled for now, and pretty straightforward to solve. However, I am stuck with Maple for some reason that I don't really get.

For the following situations (as you can see from the above), Maple gives me a solution

- Solving the two equations without boundary conditions.
- Solving the first equation with the boundary condition.

Now when I combine both, I get an error-message

> Error, (in dsolve) found the following equations not depending on the
>   unknowns of the input system: {diff(diff(Q(x, y), y), y) = 0}

If I explicitly define P and Q as the unknowns (which I took as a hint) (see last line of the code)

> Error, (in dsolve) received an indication of {Q} as an unknown of the
>   problem, and found the related function(s) {Q(x, y)}, not depending on
>   {y}. Please specify the functionality of the unknown {Q} explicitly

**Notes**

- If I define Q as a function of y only in e2, then the dsolve statements works, but this is not what I want
- I've looked into pdsolve, but without any luck so far. I.e I tried `pdsolve({e1,e2,cond});` This however gives no error messages, but also no output.
- I've searched a bit online for the error messages I got, but this didn't get me any further unfortunately.
- If y define P in e1 as a function of x and y `P(x,y)` and set `cond:=P(x,0)=0`, then dsolve does not give any output.

**What I am trying to solve**

The actual problem I am trying to solve, is as follows.

```
d^4 P(y) / dy^4 = 0
d^2 Q(x,y) / dy^2 = 0
P(y=0) = 0
```

How can this set be solve in Maple in one command?
I know the answer should be

```
P(y) =1/6 C1 y^3 + 1/2 C2 y^2 + C1 y
Q(x,y) = F1(x) y + F2(x)
```

Any hints/advice is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is completely procedural and mathematical.

Consider that first error:

> Error, (in dsolve) found the following equations not depending on the unknowns of the input system: {diff(diff(Q(x, y), y), y) = 0}

What this is telling you is you have a constant relation. Literally, the first derivative of your function `Q(x,y)` is some constant, `C`, and further attempts to find the next derivative bomb out because you've gone as low as you can go. To be entirely pedantic, [the evaluation *should* be zero,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative_of_a_constant) but this doesn't seem to be a case that Maple supports.

The second error message appears to be telling you that when you define `P` and `Q` as your unknowns, you still don't have your true unknown, `y`, bound to the solver. This also causes Maple difficulty.

I think if we saw your definition for `Q(x,y)`, we would discover very quickly that, at least according to Maple, the function isn't actually dependent upon any value of `x`. This is what's causing part of your difficulty.

Additionally, I'm unclear why you're calling [`diff`](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=diff) at all, as taking the derivative and second derivative of two functions doesn't seem to be what you want to do. Perhaps these should be replaced with [`dsolve`](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=dsolve), with your conditions specified as [here](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=dsolve#examples)?

Comment: Thanks for your kind answer. There may be some misunderstanding here, as I don't have any function `P` and `Q`. I have this set of (for now) uncoupled equations that I want to solve with ICs. I defined the DEs with `diff`. I also defined them using `D()`, but this gives me the same result. Indeed, `Q` is nowhere dependent on `x`, so the integration constants should be functions of `x`. So the first derivative of `Q` with respect to `y` should be `C(x)`, not just `C`. This is what Maple does in the single DE case, but in the coupled set, it is not able to (see also my edit)

Comment: I see. So you _are_ attempting to use the derivatives of these functions directly to solve your ODE. Sorry for the confusion. -- The trouble is, `x` is still unbound in your DE when you call `dsolve` in your first example. Going back to Maple's evaluation of `{diff(diff(Q(x, y), y), y) = 0}`, perhaps it is as simple as defining `P` in terms of `x`, such that the evaluation becomes `{diff(diff(Q(x, y), y), x) = 0}`? It seems like a simple issue of variable naming and dependencies.

Comment: Not necessarily, depending on the binding of your function and the binding of its unknowns. But, I wonder. What happens when you reorder the terms by running `dsolve(e2,e1,cond)`, without curly braces?; [The documentation](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=dsolve) seems to expect this ordering, and the unpacking of terms agrees.

Comment: That is actually a good suggestion, it only gave me this error: `Error, (in ODEtools/info) Required a specification of the indeterminate function`

Comment: For `e2`, specify which unknown you wish to solve. [Here's the documentation you need](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=requiredspecificationofindeterminatefunction). I believe this becomes: `e2:=diff(Q(x,y),y,y)=0,x`, if the indeterminate is indeed just `x`.

Comment: Getting closer ans closer: `dsolve(e2,e1,cond,Q(x,y));` now gives me `Error, (in ODEtools/info) expected the indeterminate function as, say, F(x) where x is of type "name" - and also cannot be a procedure name. Received: [Q(x, y)]`

Comment: `Q` isn't bound in the scope of that function. So, [I read this](http://paws.kettering.edu/~ktebeest/maple/odes4.html). What does `dsolve(e2(x),e1,cond)` say about the matter?

Comment: With `e2:=diff(Q(x,y),y,y)=0,x;` I get `Error, (in ODEtools/info) Not an ODE w.r.t. x(x)`. Without the `,x` again I get `Error, (in ODEtools/info) Required a specification of the indeterminate function`

Comment: Alright. Let's try: `e2:=diff(Q(f(x),y),y,y)=0,f(x);`, where your indeterminate function becomes `f(x)`, and see if it binds its mathematical primitives properly to this function of `x`. If this doesn't work, I admit that I'm stumped and will simply need to sit with the [Maple function documentation](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=function) to unwind how to make this work.

Comment: Unfortunately: `Error, (in ODEtools/info) Not an ODE w.r.t. f(x)`. This is driving me nuts in the meantime :P

Comment: Same here. Sorry I couldn't sufficiently root out the problem for you.

Comment: No worries, thanks for thinking with me here. I upvoted your answer of course, but cannot award the bounty unfortunately!